# Running TFS 2008 build definitions with TFS 2010

Tags: tfsbuild

I am in the process of upgrading my builds from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010, and in the meanwhile, I am using the Upgrade template to use the TFS 2008 build definitions. I have installed both a build controller and build agent on the machine that used to run previous builds while I was on TFS 2008. The said machine still has TFS 2008 build service installed.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
```

It seems like the first Import target causes the following error, but I can't figure out how to resolve it (the file path is from the machine running the upgrade template on TFS 2010.

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation
.Build.targets (278): The "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.GetBuildProperties"
task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation 
Server 2010\Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or 
assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the 
assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public 
class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.'
```

I have tried the solution offered in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/tfsbuild/thread/fb35ad58-f241-43ba-8f17-82d7a520f9bb), but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the the imports are pointing to the 2008 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.dll

so `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) == what?`

Looing at the error message : its

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation 
Server 2010\Tools\
```

Run the build with /verbosity:diagnostic to see what the variables are then, correct them in the team build rsp file.

Comment: Well, I think the problem was that my Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file was never upgraded to the 2010 version for some reason... I've since replaced the file and moved on to new problems... :)